# Software with feedback feature for midi input based on sheet music

Tags: midi

I am looking for a software that matches my piano play with given sheet music via midi - i.e. software that gives me feedback if sth. was played wrong.

Basically the functionality that learning apps like FlowKey or Skoove offer - but I want to use my own sheets music.

What is the best software for this?

---

I found Synthesia doing this.

But what I am missing for Synthesia - it gives no feedback for dynamic and articulation. Are there other tools that are able to provide this?